# How can I record ui event data to generate ui heatmap in standard salesforce

Tags: lightning, ui

It would be awesome to have statistics on how users interact with apps in salesforce, both the standard ui and the custom ui. For instance, I want to track ui interactions in lightning service console.

In a completely custom built website I would use google analytics or something like heatmap.it, but as far as I am aware, this is not possible if I want to capture what parts of the standard ui, the user clicks on.

Anyone aware of any solutions out there for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

May not be completely what you want, but you could utilize [Event Monitoring](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/event_monitoring/event_monitoring_intro) here to at least get some of the information for your use case.

Two of the event types that seems to fit your use case are:

- [Lightning Page View Event Type](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_lightningpageview.htm)

  > Lightning Page View events represent information about the page on which the event occurred in Lightning Experience and the Salesforce mobile app. A Lightning Page View event tracks the page a user visited, how long the user spent on the page, and the load time for the page
- [Lightning Interaction Event Type](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_lightninginteraction.htm)

  > Lightning Interaction events track user actions in Lightning Experience and the Salesforce mobile app, such as the user clicking, tapping, or scrolling on a page.

Comment: It might not be but it's definitely along the lines. Thank you for the heads up though. Am I right to say that to use event monitoring, I need to purchase a Shield license?